# combinatorial block design

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry, combinatorial-designs

Suppose that $(X, B)$ is a $2-(v, k, \lambda)$ design. For $x \in X$, let $r_x$ be the number
of blocks in $B$ containing $x$. Show that
$r_x(k − 1) = λ(v − 1)$. Secondly, deduce that $r_x$ is independent of the choice of $x$, and this common value $r$ of $r_x$ satisfies the equation $vr = bk$.

I'm quite confused about how to begin this question. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412579/symmetrical-combinatoral-block-design/3412651#3412651

Comment: @Aqua that's a nice solution to the former part of the question, but I still am stumped on how I start to deduce the second part?

Comment: What is $b$? As far as I remember $r_x$ is by definition equal to $k$ for all $x\in X$. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: What is $b$? ...